# my program is not responding to any request get nor post but database is correctly connected and everything else is working properly with no error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
const express = require("express")
const app =express()
const mongoose =require("mongoose");
const cors=require('cors');
const FeedbackModel=require('./models/feedback')
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors);
mongoose.connect("the url no prblm here")
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})
```

> the get method is working fine before after i was working on my
> frontend it stoped working

```
app.get("/getfeedback",(req,res)=>{
FeedbackModel.find({},(err,result)=>  {
        if(err)
        {res.json(err)
        }
        else
        {res.json(result)

        }
    });
 })
```

> the app is working fine but if i call for any request the url keep on
> loading without any response it just keeps on spinning

```
app.post("/addfeedback",async(req,res)=>{
const feedback=req.body;
const newFeedback= new FeedbackModel(feedback);
await newFeedback.save();
res.json(feedback);
})
app.listen(3001,()=>{`enter code here`
console.log("Server runs in port 3001");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package incorrectly.

It has to be called and then it returns whatever value is necessary to the middleware.

Imagine a function that returns a function, the first has to be called to reach the second one.

Try this

```js
app.use(cors());
```